# Template 404 Redirect

Tags: templates, 404, redirection

Do you know if it's possible to redirect to a specific 404 page when a template group isn't found rather than just show the 404 with the incorrect url?

For example,

If I go to `example.com/nonexistant-templategroup/` I need it to redirect to `example.com/404/` rather than stay as `/nonexistant-templategroup/` showing the 404 template.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that by doing the following:

1. Make a template group called `404.group` and in that template group create an `index.html` template (this will be your 404 template)
2. Set *"Enable Strict URLs"* to *"Yes"* in your [Global Template Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html)
3. For the *"404 Page"* setting choose *"404/index"* (the template you created in step 1 above), again in your Global Template Preferences
4. In `404.gorup/index.html` put the following conditional

   ```
   {if segment_1 != "404" OR segment_2 != ""}
       {redirect="404/index"}
   {/if}
   ```

This will ensure that when a 404 is triggered and your 404 template is shown, it will be further redirected to the *vanity* 404 URL of just `/404`.

There are a couple potential downsides to doing this, though.

- You won't have a record of these 404 URLs in Google Analytics so that you can see what URLs are erroring.
- The http status will not actually be 404, but 302 (redirect). You could get around this by using the [HTTP Header plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/http-header) and deliberately setting the status with `{exp:http_header status="404"}`

Comment: Thats perfect thanks! I was actually doing all of that apart from step 4, that was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: You're welcome!